# Can I overload the insertion operator to take a templated-STL container?

Tags: c++

I have this example which is about STL containers so i'm reading about them, It gets so tedious for me to repeatedly use a `range-for` loop to print the content of a container. So I thought about overloading the insertion operator `<<` thus I can write: `std::cout << container << std::endl;`.

```
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::list<T>& v) {
    for (const auto& e : v)
        out << e << ", ";
    return out;
}

int main() {

    std::list<int> vi{ 10, 24, 81, 57, 2019 };

    vi.pop_back();
    std::cout << vi << std::endl; // 10, 24, 81, 57,

    std::deque<std::string> names{ "Hello", "STL Containers" };
    std::cout << names << std::endl; // error here. Bacause I've not overloaded << to take a std::deque<T>


}
```

As you can see above I find it so comfortable to print a `list` of some type. The problem is I can only print a list but not other sort of container like a `vector` or `deque`...

So how can I overload `<<` to take a container of type `T<U>` or Should I specialize it for all the containers?
In a real example Shouldn't I do that?

Comment: Here's your [mcve](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37f3b7bde8837169).

Comment: Short answer: you should not do that. Some standard containers (aka types that meet the requirements of containers) ALREADY have an insertion operator.   For example, `std::string` - and generating an insertion operator for all containers would cause a diagnosable error due to ambiguity whenever you try to output those containers (i.e. two equally viable insertion operators, and no reason to prefer one over the other).

Comment: Why are you outputting standard containers _so_ much that it becomes "tedious"? That's a strange program! Perhaps your program isn't quite doing what it should be doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide the following overload :

```
template <class...>
using void_t = void;

template <class... Args>
constexpr bool exists_t_v(){
  return std::is_same<void_t<Args...>, void>::value;
}


template <class Container, class = std::enable_if<
  exists_t_v<
    decltype(std::begin(std::declval<Container>())),
    decltype(std::end(std::declval<Container>()))
  >()
>>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Container&& container){
  for(const auto& e : std::forward<Container>(container))
    os << e << ',';

  return os;
}
```

This will let any instance `container` of the type `Container` for which `std::begin(container)` and `std::begin(container)` are defined to use the overload.

One of the issues with solutions like these is `std::string` support as well as any type that already provide its own overload for which `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are defined.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that is not possible, I tried to put iterators in the `operator<<` but even they require to have exact iterator type, this is the closest possible solution using `ostream_iterator`:

```
template<class T2, class T>
void showT(ostream&out, T b, T end){
    out << '[';
    copy(b, end, ostream_iterator<T2>{out, ", "});
    out<<"]";
    return;
};
```